# Is there user defined way to perform the matrix multiplication without using for loops or loops in general?

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
ofstream o("new1.txt"); o << "\nMATRIX MULTIPLICATION\n";
int a[100][100],b[100][100],c[100][100],x,y,z,i,j,k,l;
cout << "enter dimensions\n";
cin >> x >> y >> z;//read the dimensions of x*y and y*z matrices
cout << "enter two matrices\n"<<"enter first matrix\n";
//read the first x*y matrix
    for (i = 1; i <= x; i++)
        for (j = 1; j <= y; j++)
            cin >> a[i][j];
//read second y*z matrix
    cout << "\nenter second matrix\n";
    for (k = 1; k <= y; k++)
        for ( l = 1; l <= z; l++)
            cin >> b[k][l];
    //print the first x*y matrix
    cout << "\nfirst matrix"; o << "\nfirst matrix\n";
    for (i = 1; i <= x; i++)
    {
        cout << "\n"; o << "\n";
        for (j = 1; j <= y; j++)
        {
            cout << a[i][j]<<"\t"; o << a[i][j]<<"\t";
        }
    }

    //print second y*z matrix
    cout << "\nsecond matrix\n"; o << "\nsecond matrix\n";
    for (k = 1; k <= y; k++)

    {
        cout << "\n"; o << "\n";
        for (l = 1; l <= z; l++)
        {
            cout << b[k][l] << "\t"; o << b[k][l] << "\t";

        }
    }
    //perform multiplication
    for (i = 1; i <= x; i++) 
        for (j = 1; j <= z; j++) 
        { c[i][j] = 0; 
          for (k = 1; k <= y; k++) 
           c[i][j] += a[i][k] * b[k][j]; 
        }
    cout << "\nresultant matrix\n"; o << "\n\nresultant matrix";
    //print the resultant matrix
    for (i = 1; i <= x; i++)
    {
        cout << "\n";
        for (j = 1; j <= z; j++)
            cout << c[i][j] << "\t";
    }

    for (i = 1; i <= x; i++)
    {
        o << "\n";
        for (j = 1; j <= z; j++)
            o << c[i][j] << "\t";
    }
    o.close();
getchar(); getchar();
return 0;
}
```

I have the above code for matrix multiplication which works fine but I am a little dizzy about how the three for loops are working at once.Is there any way to understand it better or any other way to achieve the multiplication?

Comment: You might want to be careful with your loop conditions. Remember that arrays are indexed from zero to size minus one, so having a conditions such as `<=` might lead to one-off errors and [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: It is a mathematical problem. You need to learn the matrix multiplication first. In fact, there is another way to perform matrix multiplication, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strassen_algorithm.

Comment: Btw, recognising that three nested loops is something that should be improved upon is a good start to developing a sense of beauty and not putting up with ugly code, or not leaving unreadable (but working) code as "done". I offer recognition and encouragement!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the code better and more readable, *abstract* and *refactor*.  I see repeditive code for each matrix and that's an obvious common function.

That's also what I call "meandering". The monolithic program does different things one after another with no separation. The main function that "read, multiply, write" should not go into detail of how any of those chores are actually performed.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could use a third-party component or library that hid the details from you, so that you could simply do something like (from the mythical `pax-matrix` library):

```
Matrix a(4, 3,   1,  2 , 3,  4,
                 5,  6,  7,  8
                 9, 10, 11, 12);
Matrix b(2, 4,   1,  2 ,
                 3,  4,
                 5,  6,
                 7,  8);
Matrix c = a.mult(b);
```

But, at some point, it will still have to use nested `for` loops - that's contained in the very *definition* of matrices.

Your best bet at understanding how looping code works is to run a sample *in your head,* actually performing the steps taught in maths textbooks.

Start with something like:

```
 / 1  2  3  4 \     / 1 2 \
|  5  6  7  8  | x |  3 4  |
 \ 9 10 11 12 /    |  5 6  |
                    \ 7 8 /
```

and work out each cell in the resultant matrix. For example the top-left cell would be the sum of products of the first row of martix 1 and first column of matrix 2, `1x1 + 2x3 + 3x5 + 4x7`:

```
( 1 2 3 4 ) x  / 1 \
              |  3  |
              |  5  |
               \ 7 /
```

That way you'll be more likely to understand the three loops. The outer two loops simply select each cell in the resultant matrix while the inner loop sums the products for setting that cell.